# WFS layer shows blank area, even though there is some information in attribute table

Tags: qgis, wfs

When I try to load WFS layer it shows blank area, even there is some information in attribute table. And instead on vector layer it shows new icon.

Here is the source:
https://www.avoindata.fi/data/fi/dataset/oulun-kaupungin-aanestysaluejako

Here is WFS link:
https://e-kartta.ouka.fi/TeklaOGCWebOpen/WFS.ashx

Answer (score 6):

Unfortunately they have configured their service to contain all the geometries as GEOMETRYCOLLECTION datatype, that QGIS does not handle. Test with

https://e-kartta.ouka.fi/TeklaOGCWebOpen/WFS.ashx?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=1.1.0&TYPENAME=gis:Aanestysalueet&MAXFEATURES=1&SRSNAME=EPSG:3133

You'll see that the returned GML contains a geometrycollection with one polygonz and one pointz geometry.

GDAL can read data from the service

```
ogrinfo WFS:"https://e-kartta.ouka.fi/TeklaOGCWebOpen/WFS.ashx" gis:Aanestysalueet
```

If you want to get the data and get rid of the geometry collections I would suggest to use ogr2ogr https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html with the `-explodecollections` option

> -explodecollections
>
> Produce one feature for each geometry in any kind of geometry
> collection in the source file, applied after any -sql option.

Answer (score 4):

There appears to be an issue with the returned GML  whether it be the default GML2, or the GML3 requested by QGIS; that is both of these requests give invalid responses:

> https://e-kartta.ouka.fi/TeklaOGCWebOpen/WFS.ashx?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=1.0.0&TYPENAME=gis:Kaupunginosat&MAXFEATURES=1&OUTPUTFORMAT=GML3

> https://e-kartta.ouka.fi/TeklaOGCWebOpen/WFS.ashx?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetFeature&VERSION=1.0.0&TYPENAME=gis:Kaupunginosat&MAXFEATURES=1&

The errors for the GML3 response are:

> Attribute 'srsName' must appear on element 'gml:MultiGeometry'.

> Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://www.opengis.net/gml":PolyhedralSurface}'. One of '{"http://www.opengis.net/gml":_Geometry}' is expected.

> Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://www.opengis.net/gml":name}'. One of '{"http://www.opengis.net/gml":coord, "http://www.opengis.net/gml":coordinates}' is expected.

The error on the GML2 response is:

> Invalid content was found starting with element '{"http://www.opengis.net/gml":name}'. One of '{"http://www.opengis.net/gml":coord, "http://www.opengis.net/gml":coordinates}' is expected.

I see that QGIS doesn't allow you to request GML2 from a WFS 1.0 service, which may be a potential issue (selection box is greyed out).